# Change Width of UITextfield Input

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

Is there a way to change the input size of my UITextield so it doesn't overlap with my "vergessen"-Button?

The Textfield is a simple TextfieldView with a width of 315. I added the "Vergessen?" Button programmatically with the code down below.

```
func createForgetButton () {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Vergessen?", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.vergessenTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 19.0)
    passwordTextField.rightView = button
    passwordTextField.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes there is :), if you can show how you've built this view, what you've tried and what's not working you may be more likely to get a good answer. All the best.

Comment: @Wez Updated the Question. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Show how you set the frames or constraints of the views. Obviously you need to change the frame/constraints of the text field so it only goes up to the edge of the button.

Comment: the white line is the whole textfield. Thats the width constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following custom class for the field. Then update `.rightPadding` field in IB or in the code to match the width of the button you have on the right.

```
/**
 * Text field with some changes according to design
 *
 * - author: Alexander Volkov
 * - version: 1.0
 */
@IBDesignable public class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    /// the left padding
    @IBInspectable public var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// the right padding
    @IBInspectable public var rightPadding: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// Text rectangle
    ///
    /// - Parameter bounds: the bounds
    /// - Returns: the rectangle
    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect: CGRect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x + leftPadding, y: originalRect.origin.y, width: originalRect.size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding, height: originalRect.size.height)
    }

    /// Editing rectangle
    ///
    /// - Parameter bounds: the bounds
    /// - Returns: the rectangle
    override public func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect: CGRect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x + leftPadding, y: originalRect.origin.y, width: originalRect.size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding, height: originalRect.size.height)
    }
}
```